# Can not import selenium webdriver after installing pillow

Tags: python, selenium, image-processing, webdriver

My python script was running as expected and then I needed to add PIL package and I installed Pyscreenshot, PIL and Pillow for image processing.

After installing these packages, import selenium statements became greyed out and I cannot longer import selenium.

I uninstalled image processing packages to restore the settings but no luck

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
#from PIL import Image


BaseUrl = "http://google.com"
browser.get(BaseUrl)
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Note : I have selenium and gckodriver installed and path also added.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what error are you getting

Answer (score 0):

PIL or Pillow does not have any relation to selenium libraries. So this should not be the issue.

Also, I did not find any initialization of browser.

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Below code works for me

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

BaseUrl = "http://google.com"
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(BaseUrl)
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Comment: Thankss for your reply, but browser initialization was part of the real script which was working fine. Not sure after the Pillow it stopped from importing.